# Struggling with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, arrays, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm totally new to android programming, I'm trying to create a friendslist class.

First, I make an array that loads objects from a database:

```
friendArray = new Friend[NumberOfFriendsInDatabase];

//gets friend objects from the database, and loads them into an array
for (int i=0;i<NumberOfFriendsInDatabase;i++){
    friendArray[i]=new Friend("","","");//swap this with an object or data from database handler.
```

then I create a listview where I want the array to be visually represented:

```
friendListView  =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.FriendsListView1);
```

and at last, I understand that I need to use an adapter to achieve this, and this is where I'm confused.

```
friendListAdapter = ArrayAdapter();
```

I'm having trouble creating the adapter, and I can't make sense of the official documentation. All I want is the friendArray in an adapter that I can use with listView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ArrayAdapter like this:

```
// A Collection which holds your values
List<YourFriendObject> list = new ArrayList<YourFriendObject>();

// fill the Collection with your data
// you should use for-each but I dont know your object
for (int i = 0; i < friendArray.length; i++)
  list.add(friendArray[i]);

// The ArrayAdapter takes a layout, in this case a standard one
// and the collection with your data
ArrayAdapter<YourFriendObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

 // provide the adapter to your listview
frienListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps to understand the basics. Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) about this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your constructive  answer, I'd thumbs up but apparently I lack the reputation!

Comment: It's not the upvote which counts it's the accepting of the answer, that other people, who have a look at your question, can consider how to solve the problem correctly.